# Solr sorting with special characters in solr 7.7

Tags: solr, icu

I need to activate sorting with special characters (e.g. german umlaut) in Solr 7.7. The current field specification is:

```
    <fieldType name="text_spell_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="de" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="de" />
            <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="de" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The documentation in Solr says regarding collation:

> Rather than specifying an analyzer within <fieldtype …​
> class="solr.TextField">, the solr.CollationField and
> solr.ICUCollationField field type classes provide this functionality

But when I change the field type to solr.ICUCollationField, the following exception occurs during startup:

```
    Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: FieldType: ICUCollationField (text_spell_de) does not support specifying an analyzer
```

How is this done right?

Comment: how did you define the field?

Comment: <field name="text_spell_de" type="collatedGERMAN" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true"/><fieldType name="collatedGERMAN" class="solr.ICUCollationField"
           locale="de"
           strength="primary" />